# Como obter o valor de um input usando o atributo name javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estava testando uns códigos e percebi que não estava conseguindo obter o valor de um `input` através do atributo **name** `document.getElementsByName().value`, mas com o `id` está funcionando normalmente. É possível obter o valor usando **name**? Se sim como devo fazer?

### Através do name

```js
function t() {
  var t1 = document.getElementsByName("01").value;
  var t2 = document.getElementsByName("02");
  
  t2.value = t1;
};
```

```html
<input type='text' name='01'/><br>
<button onclick='t()'>CONFIRMAR</button><br>
<textarea id='02'></textarea>
```

### Através do id:

```js
function t() {
  var t1 = document.getElementById("01").value;
  var t2 = document.getElementById("02");
  
  t2.value = t1;
};
```

```html
<input type='text' id='01'/><br>
<button onclick='t()'>CONFIRMAR</button><br>
<textarea id='02'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O elemento que você quer obter deve ter um atributo `name`:

```
<input type='text' id='01' name="campo" value="foo">
                             ↑
```

Como o método `document.getElementsByName` retorna um *node list* (lista de nós), você deve obter um dos elementos da lista através de um índice, que começa com `zero` (`[0]`), onde `[0]` é o primeiro elemento da página, `[1]` o segundo e assim consecutivamente:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByName("campo");
console.log(el[0].id);
console.log(el[1].id);
```

```html
<input type='text' id='01' name="campo">
<input type='text' id='02' name="campo">
```

O `document.getElementsByName` pode ser útil para usar com *radio buttons*, já que num grupo deles, cada membro possui o mesmo `name`:

```html
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M"> Masculino
</p>
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F"> Feminino
</p>
```

> Como um `id` deve ser único na página o, `document.getElementById` não
>   retorna um *node list*, apenas o elemento selecionado. Tanto que o nome é no *singular* (*getElement*) e não no plural (*getElements*).

Comment: Então se eu for obter elementos com nomes diferente eu mantenho como `[0]` para os primeiros? exemplo `document.getElementsByName("nome")[0].value` e `document.getElementsByName("sobrenome")[0].value`

Comment: Sim, exatamente. O `[0]` pega o primeiro com o name especificado.

Answer (score 2):

Neste código há um erro, no seu HTML, o `textarea` não tem atributo `name`, somente o `id`, setado para `"02"`, mas no seu Javascript você tenta encontra-lo pelo `name`, realmente nunca vai encontrar. Mas mesmo que corrija este erro, há mais um problema. Como já disseram, a função `getElementsByName` retorna uma lista de elementos, ou seja, você precisará localizar o elemento que você quer, neste caso, ele está no índice 0, mas se você tiver outro elemento como a mesma propriedade `name` (da mesma TAG, ou diferente) antes dele, você vai ter um erro, pois o índice 0 não vai ser o elemento que você quer.

O mais interessante é você utilizar as funções nativas [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) ou [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), pra fazer seleções CSS mais específicas. No seu caso você pode usar
`document.querySelector('input[name="01"]')` ao invés de `document.getElementsByName("01")`, que vai retornar um NodeElement e você poderá acessar a propriedade `value`. Essa seleção garante que o resultado vai ser um elemento da TAG `input` e atributo `name="01"`, coisa que o `getElementsByName` não faz.

Aqui vai o exemplo corrigido

```js
function t() {
  var t1 = document.querySelector('input[name="01"]');
  var t2 = document.querySelector('textarea[name="02"]');
  
  t2.value = t1.value;
};
```

```html
<input type='text' name='01'/><br>
<button onclick='t()'>CONFIRMAR</button><br>
<textarea name='02'></textarea>
```

Lembrando que, se você não quiser especificar a TAG do elemento na seleção CSS, você pode utilizar asterisco, desta forma: `'*[name="01"]'`. Mais exemplos de seleções CSS você pode ver no W3Scools: [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) e [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName` retorna um NodeList de elementos, por isso não tem a propriedade `.value`
Use `document.getElementsByName("01")[0].value` e `t5[0].value`